# How to install a `.deb` package, when the install button is disabled?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I am trying to install this deb package http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/utils/b43-fwcutter but whenever I doubleclick it the install button is disabled.

I don't have internet connection.

Comment: Most likely you are missing dependencies and that's why software center refuses to install.

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies?

Comment: Do you have the package locally?  Has it been downloaded?

Comment: How to find out what I am missing? Software center doesn't prompt anything. @Mitch yes, I downloaded it.

Comment: You also need `firmware-b43-installer`. One big problem is that package needs an internet connection to download the Broadcom binary firmware package, so it's easiest if you can somehow get an Ethernet connection for just a few minutes.

Comment: then it's done... Don't have cable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open a terminal and go to the directory where the .deb file in loacated.

Then execute

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_015-9_i386.deb
```

This should work.

**Note:** *Most of the time, this should not work if you don't have all dependent packages installed. But I [inspected this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/utils/b43-fwcutter), and see that, it is only dependent on `libc6` package, which is automatically installed by Ubuntu. Hence it should work*.

Comment: or you can install multiple deb package by typing `sudo dpkg -i *.*deb`

Comment: @Kaktarua, yes, only if you have all dependencies in the folder.

Comment: Thanks Anwar Shah you answer helped me to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but you can install a `.deb` file by right-clicking on it and then selecting the <kbd>Open in software center</kbd> option.

This will take you to the software center from where you can install it very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GDebi if you want to install .deb packages via a GUI. I've used it to install Kernel updates before, it does a great job.

Look for GDebi in the Software Center.

Stay Awesome and Always Believe